# Fill form by clicking anchors with javascript or jquery

Tags: forms, input, fill

What I need is a script to fill form inputs by clicking on links on the same site with the link text. Yesterday I found a solution to do this, but It's only the half way to my exceptation. The script must fill the first empty input field. I've illustrated it on the image:

[image]

In the same time the clicked link must disappear. In this case the result would be:

[image: http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/8010/slika2c.jpg]

I've no idea how to do it in javascript weather in jquery. Please help!